# no symbols in vmlinux

Tags: linux-kernel, oprofile

I need `oprofile` to display detailed information about what happens inside the kernel instead of labeling it as `/no-vmlinux`.

To be able to provide `oprofile` with kernel symbols, I used the script `extract_vmlinux` available in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.7/scripts` to obtain `vmlinux` from the compressed version `vmlinuz`.

Then I called `operf` with the option `--vmlinux path_to_vmlinux`.
However, `operf` displays the following error message:

> Unable to obtain vmlinux end address The specified vmlinux file
>   (/tmp/vmlinux) does not seem to be valid. Make sure you are using a
>   non-compressed image file (e.g. vmlinux not vmlinuz)

By following this error message in the code of `operf`, I figured out that it occurs most likely after calling `objdump -t` (option -t is to "Print the symbol table entries of the file." according to the manpage of objdump)
And when I run: "`objdump -t vmlinux`", I get the following output:

```
vmlinux:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Did you provide the location of `System.map`?

Comment: As far as I've seen, oprofile doesn't work with System.map, it requires to have a vmlinux file